# How to do full outer joins in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am receiving the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer join on PERSON.idnum=ADVISOR.student full outer join DIGITAL on ADVISOR.st' at line 1

When trying to run the following code:

```
select fname, lname, rname, advisor_name, smaddr FROM PERSON FULL OUTER JOIN on PERSON.idnum=ADVISOR.student FULL OUTER JOIN DIGITAL on ADVISOR.student=DIGITAL.idnum ;
```

I tired using union but not sure if I am doing it right because I am still getting a syntax error.

```
select fname, lname , rname , advisor_name , smaddr from PERSON full outer join on PERSON.idnum=ADVISOR.student left outer join DIGITAL on ADVISOR.student=DIGITAL.idnum 
 union 
select fname, lname , rname , advisor_name , smaddr from PERSON full outer join on PERSON.idnum=ADVISOR.student right outer join DIGITAL on ADVISOR.student=DIGITAL.idnum;
```

This table needs to output fname, rname, lname, advisor name, and twitter account from the following tables and if a person does not have an advisor paired with them or something then it will return null:

```
PERSON
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+---------+----------+
| idnum | lname   | fname    | rname                   | private | linkblue |
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+---------+----------+
| 22222 | Clemens | Timothy  | clemens.timothy@uky.edu |       0 | tgcl258  |
| 40256 | South   | William  | south.william@uky.edu   |       1 | weso123  |
| 55555 | North   | Dan      | north.dan@uky.edu       |       0 | ddno453  |
| 56732 | Cox     | Courtney | NULL                    |       1 | cco546   |
| 68123 | Smith   | Terry    | smith.terry@uky.edu     |       1 | tlsm321  |
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+---------+----------+
ADVISOR
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+
| student | advisor | student_name  | advisor_name  | sdate | edate |
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+
|   40256 |   40256 | William South | Abby Tanner   | NULL  | NULL  |
|   68123 |   68123 | Terry Smith   | Nicole Taylor | NULL  | NULL  |
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+
DIGITAL
+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| idnum | smtype   | smaddr                       |
+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| 22222 | facebook | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| 40256 | facebook | facebook.com/south.william   |
| 68123 | facebook | facebook.com/smith.terry     |
| 22222 | twitter  | twitter.com/clemons.timothy  |
| 40256 | twitter  | twitter.com/south.william    |
| 68123 | twitter  | twitter.com/smith.terry      |
+-------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do a `full outer join`?  It is almost never necessary.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not mentioned your table that you want to join to in your first join

```
   SELECT
        fname,
        lname ,
        rname ,
        advisor_name ,
        smaddr
    FROM
        PERSON
    FULL OUTER JOIN ON ADVISOR 
        PERSON.idnum = ADVISOR.student
    FULL OUTER JOIN DIGITAL ON
        ADVISOR.student = DIGITAL.idnum ;
```

If the db does not support full join then do union

```
select
    fname,
    lname ,
    rname ,
    advisor_name ,
    smaddr
from
    PERSON
left join ADVISOR on
    PERSON.idnum = ADVISOR.student
union select
    fname,
    lname ,
    rname ,
    advisor_name ,
    smaddr
from
    PERSON
left join DIGITAL on
    ADVISOR.student = DIGITAL.idnum ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am answering because Omari's answer is about the worst possible way to implement something resembling a `full join`:

- It unnecessarily duplicates data.
- It then incurs extra overhead for removing the duplicates.
- It doesn't even match `full join` because of the duplicate elimination and handling of `null` values.

All that said, you describe this:

> This table needs to output fname, rname, lname, advisor name, and twitter account from the following tables and if a person does not have an advisor paired with them or something then it will return null

This description is a `left join`, not a `full join`:

```
select p.fname, p.lname , p.rname , a.advisor_name, d.smaddr
from person p left join
     advisor a
     on p.idnum = a.student left join
     digital on
     on p.idnum = d.idnum ;
```

It is very hard to imagine how `advisor.student`, `advisor.advisor` or `digital.idnum` could NOT refer to a valid person.  If they did, then a `full join` *might* be appropriate.